# MySql or Json for multi request?

Tags: php, mysql, json

I have 1000 json files in my server and users request their file with something like this `mysite.com/request.php?file=id` and i should show them `id.json` .But before i show them i should check if `id.json` need to be updated or not .

My json files are something like this:

```
{
  "response": {
        ......,
  "lastupdate":14323342

 }
}
```

In last update i store the last update time in seconds and if the current time is bigger than 1 hour i should update my file from somewhere else .
Now my question : Is it good to save `lastupdate` in Mysql or in each json file ?
If i use mysql i need 1000 rows and each row should have 2 columns ,first columns are `id` and second columns are `lastupdate`.And my users are more than 10,000 and each day and server hardwares is important for me.

Comment: MySQL: if you index the file ID (which is probably is by default if you make it a primary key) then it will be very fast to retrieve the last update time. If you use flatfile, there will be no indexing as far as I'm aware, so MySQL is probably a little faster in the long run.

Comment: i will store the name of file in `id` column so you mean mysql is better but what about the server resource ?which way is optimized

Comment: You can optimise the database a little by adding an index on the id column if it's not index already, which will allow MySQL to quickly find the record you're after. You can't do that with a flatfile lookup.

Comment: Is it possible to use file system update time directly and don't read/write it in json file itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're grabbing a specific file (not opening a "flatfile database" and search something), it should be faster than querying a mySQL db.

---

A thought form a similar case; if the same ID could be requested a number of times in less than an hour, AND if you actually don't need to update the last update time in the "json file" until a user is asking, then when there's a request to `request.php?file=id` I'll:

```
"try" to get and decode the json file, put the decoded to (eg) $data

if the file doesn't exist OR lastupdate is more than an hour
{

    update the lastupdate, and update $data

    update the json file

}

show $data
```

... it's basically a simple caching to try to get data from file instead of db, and to prevent updating (db query) when no one is asking.

You can safely `rm -rf` everything in the "cache folder" anytime.

```
if ( $data = file_get_contents( 'path_to_cache/' . $id . '.json' ) )
    $data = json_decode( $data );

if ( empty( $data ) || $data->lastupdate < time() - 3600 )
{
    // do query, put to $data
    // encode $data, put to 'path_to_cache/' . $id . '.json'
}

echo $data;
```

... and actually, in my case I don't need to put lastupdate to DB. So I can simply use the json file's filemtime().

Comment: I have this structure user send for example `?id=new_york` then i see the last update and current server time if i should update(it is more than 1 hour) i will update and show `new_york.json` otherwise i show `new_york.json` in this way it's better to save `lastupdate` in json . Am i right ?

Comment: I think you're right but I'm not sure. You wrote new_york.json twie. I'll fix the pseudo code above to explain it betterk, please hold :-)

Comment: After reading the question again I think the code above needs a few modification to suit you situation. Just remember: 1) Grabbing a file is faster then querying "another server". 2) You can even do some caching, and some IF condition, to minimize db query even more.

Comment: But if i want to store `lastupdate` in json : for example if i should update i need first decode my json then update my json file with somewhere else then add `lastupdate` to my json then encode and store  it in my folder and show the file to user but with Mysql only need one query to see `lastupdate` of my given `id` and override my json with the new one . Now i'm confounded :-)

Comment: @Saeed It's so obvious: avoid parsing files. If you can get `lastupdate` from OS or DB or memory cache - get it there.